Intermittent network after changing a kvm guest from alma9 to opensuse tumbleweed
I want opensuse tumbleweed in a tektonic vps.  Tektonic only offers other distributions preinstalled.  So first i figured i’d try it here, i installed an alma9 vm on one of our centos8.4 kvm hosts, then did a remote install of opensuse tumbleweed into the vm.
It seemed fine at first but i soon noticed intermittent network response.  It seems fine for minutes at a time, then seems dead for a few minutes, then comes back alive again, soon enough that reconnecting isn’t needed, but repeatedly dead for minutes at a time for no apparent reason.  Meanwhile other VMs, alma VMs, and an opensuse tumbleweed VM (that was installed directly via virt-install) are all having no trouble.
I’m curious what could cause such intermittent behavior.  When changing a kvm guest from alma9 to opensuse tumbleweed is there something else that needs to be accordingly adjusted?
